# Magento : How to Solve Fatal Error SetDateRange()

Tags: admin, magento-1, reports, date

When I try to filtering report by date range in admin, It show me error like this.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setDateRange() on boolean in
>   app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Report.php
>   on line 50

Any one have idea?

Comment: Please share your full code.

Comment: i have install two mageto in local in first magento it is working fine but in second magento it shows error